# Как скрыть view, если он не используется?

Tags: android, xml, view

Есть вьюшка1. Когда заполняю ее данными, она появляется. А когда не заполняю, то ее не видно, но так как она относительно ее расположена другая вьюшка2, то вместо вьюшки1 остается пустое пространство.

Как сделать полностью скрыть вьюшку1, если ее не использую? Может, атрибут какой есть?

Comment: view1.setVisibility(View.GONE) вам не подходит?

Comment: @AndriyMartsinkevych спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.setVisibility(View.GONE)` - Вью скрыта и не занимает место
`.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` - Вью скрыта но занимает место
`.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` - Вью видна

Answer (score 4):

Можно установить `view1.setVisibility(View.GONE)`. Тогда android не будет учитывать его при отрисовке.