# Recyclerview не растягивается при освобождении места в layout несмотря на match_parent

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-animation, android-constraintlayout

Ломаю голову и рою гугл уже несколько дней, не могу понять, по какой причине recyclerView не растягивается при появлении свободного пространства.

Задача такая: при прокрутке списка (recycler) вниз на хотя бы 1 элемент, view-элементы над списком "ужимаются" и дают дополнительное место для списка. "Ужимаю" я их с помощью анимации и библиотеки expectAnim. Привожу ниже xml layout'а, а так же скрины проблемы и фрагмент кода анимации.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight">

<include layout="@layout/holder_loading" android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/layoutLoadingHolder"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutTitle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textLTitle"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageIcon"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textLTitle"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/..."
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/..."
    android:layout_width="31dp"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textH2Title"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/normal_primary_text"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageIcon"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/..."
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/..."
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/..."
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/..."/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textLTitle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/..."
    android:background="@drawable/btn_background"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textH2Title"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/..."
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/..."
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/..."
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/..."
    style="@style/AppTextAppearance"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageBackIcon"
    android:layout_width="13dp"
    android:layout_height="13dp"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/fragments_back_icon"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textLTitle"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textLTitle"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/..."
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/..."/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textTime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/colorFourthText"
    android:textSize="@dimen/normal_primary_text"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textLTitle"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/..."
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/..."
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/..."/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/colorFourthText"
    android:textSize="@dimen/normal_primary_text"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textTime"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textLTitle"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/..."
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageTimer"
    android:layout_width="14dp"
    android:layout_height="14dp"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/..."
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textCurrentTime"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textLTitle"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/..."
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/..."
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/..."/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textCurrentTime"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
    android:textSize="@dimen/normal_primary_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textLTitle"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/..."
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/..."
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/..."/>

<me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
    android:id="@+id/textH3TitleH"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
    android:textSize="@dimen/big_secondary_text"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textNum"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textTime"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/..."
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/..."
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/..."
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/..."/>

<me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
    android:id="@+id/textH3TitleA"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
    android:textSize="@dimen/big_secondary_text"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textNum"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textH3TitleH"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/..."
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/..."
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/..."
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/..."/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textNum"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
    android:textSize="@dimen/big_primary_title"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/..."
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/..."
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/..."
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/..."
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/..."
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/..."
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/..."
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textCurrentTime"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/..."
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/..."
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/..."/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/viewLine"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/colorFourthText"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textH3TitleA"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/..."
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/..."
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/..."
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/..."
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/..."/>

<com.mindorks.placeholderview.ExpandablePlaceHolderView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewLine"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/..."
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/..."
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/..."
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/..."
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/..."
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/..."
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

А вот как это выглядит в результате:
[image: элементы не ужаты]

[image: и после анимации]

При этом не суть важно, если ресайкл перемещается вслед за линией, например, то такое же пространство у него появляется ПОД ним.

А как заставить его растягиваться? Пробовал и setHasFixedSize(false), и получать layout и через params.height задавать значение, а после requestLayout() дёргать. Но всё без толку.

Может быть я вообще не под тем углом смотрю на задачу?

Comment: Что за библиотека не знаю, но суть в том, что вы после того как "ужимаете" лэйаут пропадает но занимает место. В стандартном виде можно сделать так: Получаете переменные события прокрутки у ресайкла и задаете условие, если скролят вверх, то всему лайауту который хотите скрыть задаете layout.setVisibility.(View.GONE) если вниз (к началу списка) то layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE), условие можете поменять как удобно, например заменить так, чтобы лэйаут скрылся как только скролл не будет равен 0

Comment: Возникала такая мысль - скрывать после анимации "проанимированные элементы" и вместо них выводить изначально скрытые. Однако возникает вопрос с привязкой ресайкла. Изначально он привязан к view (на скрине линия над ним). Если я её делаю GONE, то у него и привязка исчезает. Программно перепривязывать к новому элементу?

Comment: Ну может изменить привязку, в основном LinearLayout сделайте вертикальную ориентацию, и уже в основной помещайте другие LinearLayout, например в первый поместите все то, что сверху и будет программно скрываться, а потом в другой линер ставьте ресайкл, и когда вы будете делать невидимым первый линер то второй линер автоматически сдвинется вверх и тем самым пространства для прокрутки станет больше

Comment: Сейчас посмотрел вашу xml разметку, там у вашего holder_loading  первым параметром идёт `invisible`,  это означает невидимый но занимает пространство, сделайте там `gone` и по идее больше ничего не надо менять, он будет пропадать и не занимать место, а сейчас он пропадает но занимает место. в целом это работает так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/696641/Как-скрыть-view-если-он-не-используется/696702#696702

Comment: На самом деле я про флаги прекрасно знаю, и на момент проигрывания анимации (т.е. когда recycler не растягивается) holder_loading уже GONE ) Просто это программно делается. Но спасибо в любом случае.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На всякий случай отвечу на собственный вопрос, мало ли кто столкнётся с похожей проблемой. Проблема была в том, что проанимированные элементы не исчезали (GONE), а... не знаю даже, что там с ними библиотека делала. Похоже, что просто оставляла за пределами видимой части экрана.

После проигрывания анимации ставлю им View.GONE, и делаю LinearLayout resize для RecyclerView - всё работает.

Правда, появились доп. проблемы, как то, что при увеличении ресайкла "вверх", список в нём надо прокручивать (через вызов scrollToPosition). Но это уже мелочи.